# Popen error: bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm trying to upgrade python2 to python3.6 and I get and error for the following code:

```
cmd = gRealPathCmd + " " + monOpts['wd']
wd = Popen(cmd, stdout = PIPE, shell = True).communicate()[0]
wd = wd.rstrip('\n')
monOpts['wd'] = wd
```

The error I get:

```
    wd = wd.rstrip('\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

From old posts I think that the opening of the file is in binary and that why I get this error but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.
What to do?

Answer (score 1):

`b'\n'` and `'\n'` are two different values. Python 3 is quite strict about the difference between `bytes` and `str`, and `wd.rstrip`, being a bound `bytes` method, expects the former as an argument, not the latter: `wd = wd.rstrip(b'\n')`.

Comment: This does not answer how to correct the problem (the *why* not the *how*); consider adding additional information to your answer about encoding bytes to str.

Comment: Sure it does; I'm not assuming that `wd` *should* be decoded (though that very well may be the intent later).

Comment: This is just restarting the error message - bytes and strings are being mixed up, but there's no solution here.  Can you get popen to return a string?  do you have to treat the reply as a set of bytes?  Is there a way to convert bytes to string.

Comment: For example,  you can add `text=True` to the original popen to make it behave the way you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bytes-literal:

```
cmd = gRealPathCmd + " " + monOpts['wd']
wd = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
wd = wd.rstrip(b'\n')
monOpts['wd'] = wd
```